# Android ListView animation when scrolling (iOS Style)

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, animation, android-listview

I would to copy the iOS Pickeron Android with the animation while scrolling.

There is an example:
[image: example].
I found some answers[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624026/android-animation-only-when-listview-scrolls-down) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696639/set-animation-on-listview-scrolling-in-android) that's not what I want.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CarouselLayoutManager](https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager) to achieve this look, with this library you will have one elevated item that will be above all others and this will give your list the desired look.

### How to use:

- In your gradle:

  ```
  implementation 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:version'
  ```
- When declaring an adapter:

  ```
  final CarouselLayoutManager layoutManager = new CarouselLayoutManager(CarouselLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

  final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
  ```

---

You can also use [Android-PickerView](https://github.com/Bigkoo/Android-PickerView) library or [WheelPicker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker), I have only worked with the first suggested library above so I don't know how those 2 will work for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much buddy ! Happy coding :)